# In Springs Velocity binding macros (or JSP taglibrary) what is the reference to "command"?

Tags: java, data-binding, spring-mvc

In Spring 3, if I have a form object like so:

```
public Person {
   String firstname = null;
   String lastname = null;
   // ... getter & setters ...
}
```

I now understand that I can receive this object as a parameter in my controller method and that Spring will bind the form parameters to the getters/setters of my Person object.

Now I want to use springs binding macros (equivalent to the JSP taglib's for binding to form objects).

All the docs I read say that there is a default "command" object (what this means I don't yet understand). It seems like I should be able to reference the Person object via a call such as:

```
#springBind("command.firstname")
```

But I don't understand where "command" comes from or what it means, and I don't understand what I need to do in my controller to make this "binding" possible.

- Do I need to add something to the model?
- Do I need to define for Spring that the Person object is the form object?
- Should I add <"command", new Person()> to the model before rendering the page, or re-rendering the page after a form submission with errors?
- What went into the controller to make "command" meaningful to the macro?

I'm confused here and just missing some really really really simple concept I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to add the command object in the `Model`. And you need to put it there already when rendering the empty form, so `model.addAttribute("command", new Person())` is correct way. On validation errors you might want to use the submitted `Person` object instead, so that the user wouldn't lose all his submission data.

Comment: Thanks! If I add an object to the model called "command" as you specified, I can successfully call $command.firstname from a velocity template, however #springBind("command.firstname") just outputs ~5 spaces. What's the purpose of #springBind? I expected it to either output the name of the field or the value of the field. The spring docs are rather short on detail here.

Comment: I haven't much used Spring with Velocity but I assume the `#springBind()` sets the `${status}` variable that you need to use to bind the fields to your object and fetch the errors.